# How do I install python gtkmozembed package or is there a replacement of python GtkMozEmbed in windows?

Tags: python, package

```
self.widget = gtkmozembed.MozEmbed()
self.widget.set_size_request(x + 18, y)
```

I can't find a binary installer of `gtkmozembed`,

is there an equivalent that can do the above ?

Answer (score 0):

You should specify what OS/platform you're on. Binary installers are OS-specific.
Also you should specify more accurately what you're trying to do. The code is pretty much out of context and it can be hard to see what you're trying to do.
I'm assuming you're trying to have an embedded browser widget in your Python app.

Gtkmozembed for Python is part of PyGTK (pygtk.org) - you'll need to install PyGTK to use gtkmozembed.

I couldn't find any binary installers, but at the bottom of pygtk.org/downloads.html, there are links to instructions for building the binary installer on different platforms.

Also this link could be helpful (assuming you're on Windows): http://faq.pygtk.org/index.py?file=faq21.001.htp&req=show

Other than gtkmozembed there exists pywebkitgtk and wx.HtmlWindow (wxWidgets) but I must admit I couldn't find much information on those.